# PHP date: Issue with calculating date within leap year

Tags: php, datetime

I am calculating weekly values comparing the last week and the same days in the year before. As we just have a leap year, my approach causes problems.

I am calculating the dates like this and perform a corresponding select:

```
$today_raw = date('Y-m-d');
$yearAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($today_raw)));
$weekAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 day', strtotime($today_raw)));
$weekYearAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($weekAgo)));

$stmt_currentWeek = $pdo->prepare("SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z BETWEEN '$weekAgo' AND '$today'");
$stmt_weekLastYear = $pdo->prepare("SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z BETWEEN '$weekYearAgo' AND '$yearAgo'");
```

It's obvious that the `SELECT` returns the wrong number of values as `$weekYearAgo` is simply wrong as it does not reflect the leap year differences.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why dont you use the dateTime object that is within PHP? it should solve your problem

Comment: Are the timestamps in your database of the same time zone as the date setting in your `php.ini`? If not, you need to conform the php date before sending it to the database.

Comment: Why don't you use SQLs built-in date functions? They should deal with this things. Something like `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use mysql DATE Functions:

```
$stmt_currentWeek = $pdo->prepare("SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)");
$stmt_weekLastYear = $pdo->prepare("SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)");
```

1 Year And 1 Week AGO:

```
DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

1 Year AGO:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

1 Week AGO:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

In the first SQL you dont need Between 1 WEEK AGO and NOW you can just rewrite it to >= 1 WEEK AGO